# VS Code's PROBLEMS detects incorrect compiler error because I named field `Min` instead of say `Lo`. Why?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code, debugging, compiler-errors

Compare the following two programs:

#### Using `Lo`

```
Wrapper wrapper = new(10.0);
double min = wrapper.Lo;


public class Wrapper {
   public Wrapper(double min) {
        Lo = min;
    }
    double Lo;
}
```

VS Code's PROBLEMS detects the correct compiler error:

> 'Wrapper.Lo' is inaccessible due to its protection level ([CS0122](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/compiler-messages/cs0122?f1url=%3FappId%3Droslyn%26k%3Dk(CS0122)))

The solution is simple: change `double Lo` to `public double Lo`.

However, I noticed that if I rename `Lo` to `Min`, then VS Code's PROBLEMS detects an incorrect compiler error

##### Using `Min`

```
Wrapper wrapper = new(10.0);
double min = wrapper.Min;


public class Wrapper {
   public Wrapper(double min) {
        Min = min;
    }
    double Min;
}
```

VS Code's PROBLEMS detects an incorrect compiler error:

> Cannot convert method group 'Min' to non-delegate type 'double'. Did you intend to invoke the method? ([CS0428](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/misc/cs0428?f1url=%3FappId%3Droslyn%26k%3Dk(CS0428)))

I was wondering why VS Code's PROBLEMS is detecting an incorrect compiler error when I use `Min`? It also happens if I use `Max`, `Average`, `Count`. Are these words special? None of them represent members of the `Wrapper` class AFAIK, so I'm confused why VS Code's PROBLEMS treats them differently than other words.

Comment: It's conflicting with LINQ methods. If you disable `ImplicitUsings` in your .csproj file you should get the CS0122 error.

Comment: I wonder why PROBLEMS isn't smart enough to know that `Min`, `Max`, etc. are not members of the `Wrapper` class.

Comment: It does know that, it's just looking for the best match and thinking that the extension methods for LINQ interfaces might be that (though I will admit that this behavior seems a little over-greedy). BTW what you're referring to as "PROBLEMS" is just a viewer for the compiler and analyzer output, you'll get the same error if you run `dotnet run` in your shell outside of VS Code. This has more to do with the compiler than VS Code / problems window.